# How to make the collision detection in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my screen I am having some apples falling to the bottom randomly and I am having a basket at the bottom. I need to know when a collision of an apple and the basket is detected.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this collision detection?

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the ported physics engines, they generally give you an ability to detect collisions. For an example you can look here: [Chipmunk Physics or Box2D for C++ 2D GameEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707106/chipmunk-physics-or-box2d-for-c-2d-gameengine)